# Correct way to write this mySQL Query select count(ag.merk) where merk = 'Ferrari' from auto_gegevens ag

Tags: mysql

The objective is to count the amount of Ferrari's in the Brand attribute.

SELECT count(ag.brand) WHERE brand = 'Ferrari' FROM auto_gegevens ag

Comment: Where last (after join)..see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html sql  may be a declarative language but the order of clauses in a select is mandatory

Answer (score 0):

Where last (after join)..see [dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) sql may be a declarative language but the order of clauses in a select is mandatory

```
SELECT count(ag.brand)  
FROM auto_gegevens ag
WHERE brand = 'Ferrari'
```